# key values in json are not accessable in angular

Tags: angularjs, json

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('myGridTable', function($http) {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    link: function(scope, element, attrib) {
      $http.get(attrib.src).success(function(response) {
        scope.rows = response.data;
      });
      console.log("message from directive");
      angular.forEach(scope.rows, function(value, key) {
        console.log(key);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing response outside of callback.

Put your loop inside success.

Try like this

```
$http.get(attrib.src).success(function(response) {
    scope.rows = response.data;
    console.log("message from directive");
    angular.forEach(scope.rows, function(value, key) {
        console.log(key);
    });
});
```